# Can't login as admin in laravel4

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, laravel-4

I have created an admin  interface and created an admin table in my database with admin and password field. In first attempt, I manually created password and I made it md5 encrypted, but soon I come to know that laravel does not support md5 encrypted password.

So I decided to create hashed password and what I did is that , **from my end user registration panel, I registered a new user which automatically creates a hashed password in the database, I copy that password and paste it into my admin table's password field**, only then was I able to login into my admin panel.

In that time , I didn't create the logout functionality, because I was just testing, so closed my browser and came in the second day, and suddenly I can't login into my admin panel with same username and password, giving the unauthorised message "The username or password you provided is wrong!"
which surprised me a lot, because with same username and password I was able to logg in my admin account the previous day. I am sure that **there is something wrong in laravel or may be there is some issues in my code** but can't figure it out. Here is the folder structure and my code

```
src/
   app/
      controllers/
                 admin/
                      AdminController.php
      model/
           admin.php
      routes.php 
      filters.php
```

**admin.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class \Admin extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface    {



    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    protected $table = 'admins';

    protected $fillable=array
    (   'username',
        'password'

    );



    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
```

**AdminController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Admin;

class AdminController extends \BaseController{

    public function AdminLogin(){
        return \View::make('admin.login');
    }

public function AdminLoginPost(){

    $auth=\Auth::attempt(array(

          'username' => \Input::get('username'),
          'password' => \Input::get('password')
            ));

    if($auth){

        return \Redirect::intended('marriage-admin');

    }else{

        return \Redirect::route('admin')->with('global','The username or password you provided is wrong!');
    }
    return \Rediret::route('admin')->with('global','Please Review Your Admin Database.');
}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi in the next path

```
In app/
     config/
        auth.php
```

You can configure the Driver, Model and Table that reference when laravel create a validation.

Comment: what does it mean, is the any issues in auth.php file.make it clear please? @Lagul

Answer (score 0):

the auth file you must add the model used for the validation laravel well as the table to which reference will do . For example in your case:

```
<?php

return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Authentication Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the authentication driver that will be utilized.
| This driver manages the retrieval and authentication of the users
| attempting to get access to protected areas of your application.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'driver' => 'eloquent',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
| Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
| is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
|
*/

'model' => 'admin',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
| table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
| default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
|
*/

'table' => 'your table here',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Password Reminder Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the settings for password reminders, including a view
| that should be used as your password reminder e-mail. You will also
| be able to set the name of the table that holds the reset tokens.
|
| The "expire" time is the number of minutes that the reminder should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'reminder' => array(

    'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

    'table' => 'password_reminders',

    'expire' => 120,

),

);
```

Comment: then what will happeb with my **user** table for my end user? because in my auth.php file, i have set model = 'User' since i have a 'User' model for my enduser registration. @Lagul

Comment: You should check with that model and ironing you should do the authentication , if admin is a user level to make it a model?